# Evaluating integral delta function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the integral below (delta function) and not sure if I evaluated correctly? The integral is the following:

$$\int^{100}_{-100}x^3\sin(2x)\delta(x^2-9)dx$$

---

I have the following $x=\pm 3$, $$\therefore \int^{100}_{-100}x^3\sin(2x)\delta(x^2-9)dx = \int^{0}_{-100}x^3\sin(2x)\delta(x^2-9)dx + \int^{100}_{0}x^3\sin(2x)\delta(x^2-9)dx= \ (-3)^3\sin(2\cdot(-3)) + (3)^3\sin(2\cdot(3)) = \ -27\sin(-6) + 27\sin(6)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from from property of delta function:

$\delta(x^2-3^2)=\frac{1}{2*3}[\delta(x+3)+\delta(x-3)]$

Your function is even, $f(x)=f(-x)$ due to symmetry you can write

$\int_{-100}^{100} x^3 \sin(2x) \delta(x^2-9)dx = 2\int_{0}^{100} x^3 \sin(2x) \delta(x^2-9)dx = 2\frac{1}{2*3}\left(\int_{0}^{100} x^3 \sin(2x)\delta(x+3)dx+\int_{0}^{100} x^3 \sin(2x)\delta(x-3)dx\right)=2\frac{1}{2*3}\left(0+27\sin(6)\right)=9\sin(6)$

Comment: You should say that you use the fomula given by @Ninad Munshi

Comment: I see, how did you get that $$\delta(x^2-3^2)=\frac{1}{2*3}[\delta(x+3)+\delta(x-3)]?$$

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Delta function has the property that

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i \frac{1}{|f'(x_i)|}\delta(x-x_i)$$

where $x_i$ are the zeros of $f$.

Comment: how do you define $\delta(f(x))$

Comment: @reuns It's a very common object that shows up in physics and engineering. One could quite literally define the distribution the way I did above, by using the "property". It is undefined if the gradient of the function vanishes at the desired points.

Comment: You should better define it as $\delta(f(x))=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}2 1_{|f(x)| < 1/n}$ (limit in the sense of distributions, if it converges) for $f\in C^1$ with finitely many simple zeros on $[-r,r]$ from $f(x) = (x-x_i)(f'(x_i)+o(1))$ you get the result

Comment: @reuns Is there any reason to? I don't see a problem with the definition $\delta_{f} = \sum_{i} \frac{1}{|\nabla f(x_i)|} \delta_{x_i}$. This is a fairly standard definition I have even seen in Hormander. Not to mention, if a student's instructor is writing statements like $\delta(x^2-9)$, a level of informality is okay. We're trying to speak to the student's level, not make our answers extraordinarily obtuse for non math students.

Comment: Well you need it if you plan to look and use $1_{|x|<100}\delta(f(x))$ which is what the OP asked. Not even mentioning things like $f(x^2+y^2-1)$. The limit definitions is what you need to show that we can't do a pairing of $\delta$ with any test function and that in the Fourier transform we have more complicated approximations of $\delta$ thus more convergence problems.

Comment: @reuns We don't need it, and neither does OP. What exactly is the purpose of your comment now? If OP is a physics or engineering student, or anyone who hasn't done a graduate course on PDEs or functional analysis, it does them no good. Rigor is good, but your comment is no more rigorous than mine. Not to mention, everything needs to have a purpose. Rigor for the audiences above has very little value.

Comment: @reuns I agree with Ninad Munshi. This property of $\delta(f(x))$ is present in most lectures ; I don't see any (didactic) interest to get around it.

Comment: @JeanMarie ??? You can't say "I agree to not give any definition of $\delta(f(x))$". If you define it as you are saying then you are loosing everything and you'll obtain dozens of dumb questions about integrals with $\delta$, with my definition you'll obtain interesting problems about limits.

Comment: Lol never meant to start this long dialogue for my question but I am a former math student where I am now trying to recollect everything I learned in school, so any additional definitions are helpful. No harm in adding additional details that reuns mentioned. Both comments are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a change of variables to standardise the argument of the $\delta$ near points where it is $0$: if $a>0$ and $0<\varepsilon \ll a$, we have
$$ \int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a+\varepsilon} g(x) \delta(x^2-a^2)\, dx = \int_{-(2a-\varepsilon)\varepsilon}^{(2a+\varepsilon)\varepsilon} g(\sqrt{u+a^2})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u+a^2}} \delta(u) \, du = \frac{g(a)}{2a} $$
putting $x = \sqrt{u+a^2}$, and similarly for the integral over the negative axis.

Comment: thanks for this different evaluation.